# RabbitMQ pop operation atomicity

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Does anyone know if the pop operation on a RabbitMQ queue is atomic?

I have several processes reading from the same queue (the queue is marked as durable, running on version 2.0.0) and I am seeing some quite odd behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by "atomic"? Also, what is your ack strategy? Do you ack each message as soon as they arrive and then work on them, or do you work on the message and then ack?

Comment: I'm using automatic acking. By atomic I mean if one process pops a message is it possible for any other processs to pop the same message. i.e. for that message to be processed twice by seperate processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your multiple processes are consuming messages *from the same queue* then they should never consume the same message.

Here are the caveats, though:

1. If a message has been delivered by the broker to one of your consumers and it rejects the message (or terminates before getting a chance to acknowledge it) then the broker will put it back on the same queue and it would be delivered to one of your remaining active consumers.
2. If your consumers are pulling from distinct queues -- each with a matching binding -- then the broker will put copies of the message on each queue and each consumer will get a copy of the same message.

Comment: It is usefuly to write a little app that will consume messages from a queue and print out all the info available in the message object. Then make another app that gets a message and prints the same. You will note that getting and consuming provide different info, and you can detect when a message has been requeued by another listener.